# Getting the max(price) for each item ordered, given multiple different prices for any ordered item

Tags: sql

If I have an items_ordered table that looks like this:

```
items_ordered

customerid  order_date  item    quantity    price
10330   30-Jun-1999 Pogo stick  1   28.00
10101   30-Jun-1999 Raft    1   58.00
10298   01-Jul-1999 Skateboard  1   33.00
10101   01-Jul-1999 Life Vest   4   125.00
10299   06-Jul-1999 Parachute   1   1250.00
10339   27-Jul-1999 Umbrella    1   4.50
10449   13-Aug-1999 Unicycle    1   180.79
```

And I want to get the max price for each distinct item in the table, given that an item could appear multiple times in this table with different prices, how would I do that, assuming that this doesn't work:

```
select item, max(price) from items_ordered;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a Group By and you're golden.

```
select item, max(price) from items_ordered group by item;
```